# Graph traversal

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

At a party with n people P1, . . . , Pn, certain pairs of individuals cannot stand each other. 
Given a list of such pairs, determine if we can divide the n people into two groups such that all the people 
in both group are amicable, that is, they can stand each other.

Comment: This looks like a problem set question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Grammatically, this does not even look like a question at all...

Comment: yeah it is a problem set question asked to me in a interview. i know it has to be done using graph traversal. But i dont have any idea on how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

One brute force solution would be to find all possible combinations of n choose n/2 people and then verify that everyone in the group is amicable, if so, then you must check everyone in the other half as well. If both sides are happy then you've found a solution. Otherwise, move on to the next combination. Obviously, this is not an ideal solution, but it does work deterministically. Typically in an interview, it is best to start with something that works and iterate on to better ideas.

A more sophisticated solution would compute the [complement graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph), then remove any edges that are not bi-directional, pick an arbitrary node to start from, use [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), mark every node found in group 1. Then pick any unmarked node, and mark every node found in group 2. If there are any remaining unmarked nodes, then the individuals cannot be divided into two amicable groups.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a G that the pairs of people cannot be in the same group has a edge between them. Use DFS in this G and set Group1 for s, and then Group2 for its successor, and then Group2.... If we can finish it, we find it, otherwise, there are some collisions, which means we can't divide them into two groups as the question asked.

Comment: I don't think this algorithm will find the groups if the graph is disconnected. For example if we have X hates Y and Z hates W. A valid solution is {X,W} and {Y,Z}.